# why is type char arr[][] incompatible with char** arr? and how to fix it

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I've built a function with the header `void function(int d, char*** w)` if i call on it like this:

```
int d;
char** arr;
//some memory allocate function here
function(d, &arr);
```

i have no problem, but like this:

```
int d;
char arr[d][d];
function(d,%arr);
```

i get this error message: passing argument 2 of (function) from incompatible pointer type
what's the difference? i learned that they're supposed to be the same type the only difference is that the arr[d][d] declaration has a set continuous part of the memory to work with

Comment: With `char **arr` passing arr gives you a pointer to a pointer.  With `char arr[d][d]` passing arr gives you a pointer to a char array.

Answer (score 2):

In most contexts, an array will decay to a pointer to its first member.  However, this does not extend past the first dimension of a multidimensional array.

This means that an array of type `char [d][d]` decays to a pointer of type `char (*)[d]`, not `char **`.  These types are incompatible.

If you define your function like this:

```
void function(int d, char arr[][d])
```

Then it can accept an array of type `char [d][d]`.

Comment: Wait, is it actually legal to have `arr`'s second dimension sized in terms of the runtime argument `d`? Did I miss some change in the C standard, or have I misunderstood the rules for multidimensional array arguments all this time? I could've sworn the second and subsequent dimensions had to be compile-time constants, but I'll admit to not doing much with them (partially because I thought they were so limited).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, this is how you can pass a VLA to a function.  A declaration would look like this:  `void function(int, char arr[][*]);`

Comment: @ShadowRanger C11 6.7.6.3p20-21 give examples.

Comment: [TIL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53795107/364696). I guess back when I learned C, C99 was new enough that the full scope of VLA usage wasn't included in my books and classes, and since pre-C99 multidimensional array arguments were so limited, I just always coded the workaround code (accept single-dimension array, index with `row * numcols + col`) and never learned I had other options.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a one-dimensional array like

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

it looks like this in memory:

```
    +---+---+---+
 a: | 1 | 2 | 3 |
    +---+---+---+
```

And if you then have a pointer to the array's first element:

```
int *ip = &a[0];
```

you get something that, by the rules of pointer arithmetic in C, works just about exactly like the array:

```
    +---+---+---+
 a: | 1 | 2 | 3 |
    +---+---+---+
      ^
      |
    +-|-+
ip: | * |
    +---+
```

But a two-dimensional array looks like this:

```
int a2[2][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 } , { 4, 5, 6 } };

    +---+---+---+---+---+---+
a2: | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Or we could draw it like this:

```
    +---+---+---+
a2: | 1 | 2 | 3 |
    +---+---+---+
    | 4 | 5 | 6 |
    +---+---+---+
```

But the problem is that this layout is *not* compatible with a pointer-to-pointer.  If we have

```
int **p2;
```

and if we initialize it to point to some pointers that point to some integers, it'll end up looking more like this:

```
    +---+
p2: | * |
    +-|-+
      |
      v
    +---+        +---+---+---+
    | *--------> |   |   |   |
    +---+        +---+---+---+
    | *-----.
    +---+    \       +---+---+---+
              `----> |   |   |   |
                     +---+---+---+
```

And the problem is that there's nothing in `a2` for our pointer `p2` to point at that'll work.  Since `p2` is a pointer-to-a-pointer, it needs to point to a pointer in order to work.  But there's no pointer anywhere in `a2`'s representation that can fill this role.